# When did chicken become a synonym of cowardice?

Tags: folklore, animals

Chicken is often used to mean someone is a coward. This is exemplified in the [game of chicken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_(game)).

When did chicken first become a synonym of cowardice?

Comment: I know the rooster on the other hand has been a sign of valor. And chickens have been appreciated for a long time. Interesting question!

Comment: [During Arthurian times](https://creative-analytics.corsairs.network/the-tale-of-brave-sir-robin-f76f561ce45c): 932 AD or thereabouts.

Comment: @spencer Sir Robin from Monty python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/When-did-chicken-become-synonymous-with-afraid-terrified/answer/Jonathon-Green?srid=Odhf&share=1) on the exact same topic:

> The primary uses, however, remain those that suggest weakness. Thus the early use to mean a girl or woman, which would become the more recent chick. Such chickens also suggest the 'cuteness' and 'fluffiness' of the creature.
>
> The first example we have of chicken meaning a coward comes in 1600. It runs thus:
>
> > 1600 W. Kemp Nine Days’ Wonder: It did him good to have ill words of a hoddy doddy! a hebber de hoy!, a chicken! a squib.